# Which context to use in flutter? What is the difference?

Tags: mobile, flutter

I am having trouble understanding the differences between the `Widget BuildContext` and the `Builder BuildContext` as of the following code snippets:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

and

```
new Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context){
```

By using the `Widget BuildContext` the SnackBar doesn't appear in the UI but an error is shown in the logs which indicates that the `Scaffold.of() Context` doesn't have a Scaffold while using the `Builder context` everything worked fine.

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
  new SnackBar(content: new Text('Processing Data')));
```

Edit: The main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'APP'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username;
  @override
  //This context
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new Container(
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text(widget.title),
                ),
              ),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            new Form(
              key: formKey,
              child:
              new Row(children: <Widget>[
                new Flexible(child:
                  new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      decoration:
                      new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Username',
                        labelText: "1",
                        labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                      ),
                      validator: (val) => val.isEmpty? 'Username can\'t be empty.' : null,
                      ),
                  ),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                new Flexible(child:
                  new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 8.0,
                      right: 8.0,
                    ),
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Password",

                      ),
                      validator: (val) => val.isEmpty? 'Password can\'t be empty.' : null,
                      obscureText: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                new Container(
                  child:
                  new Builder(
                    //And this context
                    builder: (BuildContext context){
                    return RaisedButton(
                      child: new Text("Sign in"),
                      onPressed: (){
                        if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world, you'd
                          // often want to call a server or save the information in a database
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          new SnackBar(content: new Text('Processing Data')));
                        }
                      },
                    );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you place the code so that we can have clear idea about Widget BuildContext and Builder BuildContext.

Comment: I added the file and commented above the contexts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better if you reference the current `Scaffold` where you want the `SnackBar` to appear in by using they `key` property.

`final GloabalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();`

```
Scaffold(
key:_key,
...
)
```

show the snack bar

```
_key.currentState.showSnackBar(mySnackBar)
```

Note that each builder method gets a `context` to be able to reference it when using widgets that needs access to this context. In your code, the `context` is being confused, if you change your `build` method `context` to be something unique like `(Buildcontext scaffoldContext)` and then use `Scaffold.of(scaffoldContext)` I am not sure if this will work as I see this confusion by in Flutter quite often.

Anyway the solution above is way cleaner.

Comment: `builder method gets a context to be able to reference it` do you mean that each Builder or widger has its own context not like in Java were each Activity(Process) has its context?

Comment: I am not aware of Java, but simply you need to be able to use BuildContext and do some things on behalf of the context you are calling (in this situation calling a top level method like showSnackbar or showDialogue ..etc) You will find that the same methodology is used when calling the parent Theme to read some data from it (InheritedWidget). You may want to refer to the docs for a complete explanation: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html